# Realm supported platforms

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

Is there any way to use the `Realm` with web ?

Can we use the great `Realm` features like [Reactive architecture](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-database/) ?

I referred the docs and i see that it only has `cross-platform support`(Mobile)

Comment: You can use Realm _in the web_ using JavaScript and Node.js. Take look in [documentation article](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/).

Comment: Realm works with NodeJS on backend side, even though it is called "Realm Mobile Database".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm does not offer a JS SDK specifically for the browser. Instead, [realm-js](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) is designed for use with React Native on mobile devices or with Node for server or desktop (Electron) use-cases. The reason for this is that opening up a Realm database requires file system access, which is not possible in a web browser.

However, this doesn't mean that you cannot use Realm within a web architecture. Since Realm offers high performance, it is a great candidate to use as the data layer within a web server. For example, you could use [realm-js](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) within an Express server providing REST APIs for a web client. This can be quite powerful especially at scale, by taking advantage of a synchronized Realm to act as a data grid across many servers (see this [blog post](https://news.realm.io/news/gantt-chart-from-github-issues-caching-architecture-using-realm/) for more info).